# Nginx webserver show server IP when use CNAME

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am new and Nginx and i really look vary nice and fast.
i have problem with CNAME domain, i have define my server block as bellow

```
server_name example.com www.example.com t.example.com ~^.*$;
```

~^.*$ i use to catch all domains

now i have one other domain which have cname as bellow
t.domain1.com CNAME t.example.com

when i open `http://t.domain1.com` in browser it show website and every thing is fine but

but i am using URL rewrite too and when i try to use URL AS bellow

```
http://t.domain1.com/abc/8765
```

Website work fine but in browser address bar URL change as bellow

```
http://192.87.xx.10/abc/8765
```

where 192.87.xx.10 is my server IP.

how can i keep the browser URL `http://t.domain1.com` even it redirect to my website?

here is my config file

```
    user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    index   index.html index.htm;

server {
     listen      80;
     server_name example.com www.example.com t.example.com ~^.*$;
     root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
         if (!-e $request_filename){
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
         }
         index  index.html index.htm index.php;
     }

location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

         fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;

         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;

         fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
         fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
     }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual nginx configuration you are using? Please include it in the question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thx for reply, i have added the config file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your nginx configuration that would cause behavior like this, that is redirecting to an IP address. The issue should be in your application.

However, there is a better way to write your configuration:

Instead of:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com t.example.com ~^.*$;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

You should use:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

The `default_server` attribute makes nginx use this `server` block for every request where any other matching `server` block is found.

However, I don't understand why you are setting up the system in this way. If you are planning to serve several domains using the same software, I recommend setting up separate copies of the software for every domain. Otherwise you will encounter different issues later on.

Then:

```
location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
     }
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```